# How to draw a simple picture?

Tags: trees

[image]

I think this problem should be relatively simple, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=probability+tree+tiks&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=wHI8Vp-HOIb3UMmiptgF#q=probability+tree+tikz

Comment: On that basis, a dupe: I've picked the current top hit from Google!